# Issue with Keyboard hook for scanning for hypen("-") and equal sign("=")

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use windows C++ Keyboard hook to use USB scanner. Problem happens during scanning if QR code/barcode contains “=” and “-“. Key board hook gets wrong hexa data( i.e. ?(ffffffbb)) for these special characters. All other character gets scan correctly It would be great if you can suggest some possible solution for this problem. Thanks for taking a looking at this and please let me know if any additional information is required.

Sample  key board hook code

```
clspec(dllexport)LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int iCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {   
        CString str, strBuffer;

        str.Format( _T("lParam =%c(%0x),wParam = %c(%0x)"), (char)lParam,  (char)lParam, (char)wParam,  (char)wParam  );
        CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString (str);

        string str1(pszConvertedAnsiString);// = temp.GetBuffer(temp.GetLength());
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("ScanData.txt",ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
        myfile<<str1<<endl;         

      //  Translation table from base characters to shifted characters.
      char    From[] = "`1234567890-=\\[];',./";
      char    To[]   = "~!@#$%^&*()_+|{}:\"<>?";

      // if not an action event or MSR is not active, go to the next hook
      if (iCode < 0 || iCode != HC_ACTION )
          return CallNextHookEx(_hook, iCode, wParam, lParam);

      // Check if shift key is pressed.
      if (wParam == 0x10 && (lParam & 0xc0000000) == 0)
      {
          myfile<<"Inside  TRUE"<<endl;
          m_bShift = TRUE;
      }
      if (wParam == 0x10 && (lParam & 0xc0000000) != 0)
      {
          myfile<<"Inside  FALSE"<<endl;
          m_bShift = FALSE;
      }      

      // clear existing buffer and post message
      if ( wParam == 0x0d )
      {
          myfile<<"End of scanning"<<endl;
          CharStringToCString( m_Buffer, strBuffer, strlen( m_Buffer ) );              
          myfile<<m_Buffer<<endl;

          m_Buffer[0] = 0;
          m_nBufferIndex = 0;
          return 1;
      }
      else
      {          
          if (m_bShift) //converting the character if shift pressed
          {
              myfile<<"Inside shift"<<endl;
              int i = 0;
              while (From[i] != 0 && From[i] != (char)wParam) i++;
              if (From[i] == (char)wParam)        // Translate to shifted
              {
                  myfile<<"Inside shift2"<<endl;
                  wParam = (int)To[i];            //   character
              }
          }       


 if ((lParam & 0xc0000000) == 0 && wParam != 0x10)
    {      
        myfile<<"Append to buffer"<<endl;
        m_Buffer[m_nBufferIndex++] = (char)wParam;       // Append character to buffer
        m_Buffer[m_nBufferIndex] = 0;
    }
    return 1;
  }

  // If not Scanner data, chain to next hook procedure
  return CallNextHookEx(_hook, iCode, wParam, lParam);
}


void SetHook()
{
        HOOKPROC hkprc;
        hhookDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("..\\Debug\\KeyboardDLL.dll")); 
        if(!hhookDLL)
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to get hhookDLL!"), _T("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        hkprc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hhookDLL, "_HookCallback@12"); 
        if(!hkprc)
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to get hkprc!"), _T("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
        else
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Scan QR/Bar code and check 'ScanData.txt'!"), _T("INFO"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        _hook = SetWindowsHookEx( 
                            WH_KEYBOARD,
                            hkprc,
                            hhookDLL,
                            0); 
        if(!_hook)
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to get _hook!"), _T("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
}

output:

    Inside else shift
    Inside else shift 2
    **lParam =(1),wParam = ?(ffffffbb) (******Wrong****** for =)**
    Inside else shift
    Append to buffer
    lParam =(1),wParam = ?(ffffffbb)
    Inside else shift
    lParam =(1),wParam = 
    (d)
    End of scanning
```

Comment: You are not getting characters, you are getting virtual key codes (which sometimes, but not always, match the ASCII code of the character printed on the key). 0xBB happens to be `VK_OEM_PLUS` (a plus key on number pad).

Comment: This answer works for the issue. Thanks for your help!